# Add a date event on a line chart in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, charts

So, I have a line chart that shows a random sales data from 2010 to 2020. But, I want to add a vertical line, or some visual resource to indicate something important that happened in 2014, for example. How can I do that in Python? Any library would do!

Comment: Could you give a little more information about what python graphing library you're using? Is it just matplotlib?

Comment: check out matplotlib's `vline`

Comment: Or you could use matplotlib's `plt.annotate()`: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using plt.axvline() with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [ 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018,2019,2020]
y = [ 1000, 1200, 2500, 1000, 1100,250]

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.title("Sales Bar graph")
plt.xlabel("year")
plt.ylabel('Sales')

#drwa a line in 2019 value
plt.axvline(x=2019, label='line at x = {}'.format(2019), c='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's perfect, but, is there a way that I can add a legend to it?

Comment: sure you can add this after axvline code:
plt.legend()